# Stanford Core NLP pipeline

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to create pipeline with NER tagging.

How to get the NER tagging in this way?

Line triggering the error:
`String nerrr = token.ner();`

Code:

```
public class NLPpipeline {

public AnnotationPipeline buildPipeline() {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    AnnotationPipeline pl = new AnnotationPipeline();

    pl.addAnnotator( new TokenizerAnnotator( false ) );
    pl.addAnnotator( new WordsToSentencesAnnotator( false ) );
    pl.addAnnotator( new POSTaggerAnnotator( false ) );
    pl.addAnnotator( new MorphaAnnotator( false ) );
    pl.addAnnotator(new TimeAnnotator("sutime", props));


    return pl;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {


    NLPpipeline nlp = new NLPpipeline();
    AnnotationPipeline pipeline = nlp.buildPipeline();
    Annotation annotation = new Annotation( "Last summer, Sali and Nadav met every Tuesday afternoon, from 1:00 pm to 3:00 pm." );
    pipeline.annotate( annotation );


    for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
        for (CoreLabel token : sentence.get( CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class )) {

            String word = token.word();
            String pos = token.tag();
            String nerrr = token.ner();
            String role = token.lemma();


            System.out.println( "=====\n" + word );
            System.out.println( pos );
            System.out.println( nerrr );
            System.out.println( role );
        }
    }
}
```

thank you very much for your answer. I tried to create a pipe like you described, but it's very slow because I have a long text and I have to divide it into sentences, and each time it loads the NER files and it takes about 45 seconds for each sentence. My project is converting user stories into test cases, and I need to identify entities in user stories.
I realized I had the opportunity to create the department once:
         SentimentAnalyzer sentimentAnalyzer = new SentimentAnalyzer ();          sentimentAnalyzer.initializeCoreNLP (); // run this only once
And send at a time, but I do not understand how I should do it

Comment: What's the error on the console ?

Comment: when the program running, he doesn't doing the NER Identification - as you see : null null ...(my comment is a link)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the NERAnnotator in your `AnnotationPipeline`. In general, I recommend creating a pipeline with `Properties` rather than explicitly from the annotator classes. This has a number of advantages:

1. You get annotator caching for free; future annotators with the same property sets don't have to be reloaded.
2. You get sensible defaults for most of the properties of an annotator.
3. You can, if you want, save the properties file as a resource file independent of the code.
4. You can still customize the annotators, by setting the appropriate properties.

For your use-case, you'd run:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

Annotation annotation = new Annotation( "Last summer, Sali and Nadav met every Tuesday afternoon, from 1:00 pm to 3:00 pm." );
pipeline.annotate( annotation );

...
```

See [the official documentation](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html) for more information.

Alternately, you can also try using the [Simple API](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/simple.html):

```
Document doc = new Document("Last summer, Sali and Nadav met every Tuesday afternoon, from 1:00 pm to 3:00 pm.")
doc.sentence(0).ner(3);  // returns 'PERSON'
doc.sentence(0).nerTags();  // returns [O, O, O, PERSON, O, PERSON, ...]
```

Or, if you know your input is a single sentence, simply:

```
Sentence sent = new Document("Last summer, Sali and Nadav met every Tuesday afternoon, from 1:00 pm to 3:00 pm.")
    sent.ner(3);  // returns 'PERSON'
```

Comment: Thank you. I would be very happy if you could look at the comment I posted above. I saw in LinkedIn that you are part of the Stanford University algorithm writers and I would be very happy if you could help me or give me examples.